# Simple, good-looking crosstabs that allow anonymization

Tags: r, crosstab, gtsummary, anonymize

Is there an easy way to annonymize crosstabs created with the tbl_cross function from the gtsummary package?

Or is there an alternative package that I can just use?
For example, I want to anonymize all values that are >5.

Comment: What do you mean with 'anonymize'?  Do you want to only do the cross table on rows having values > 5 in some particular column? Do you want to just remove column and row names?

Comment: can you share your data and code?

Comment: Anonymization can be done *before* aggregation/summarizing, I think trying to do it on the output from `gtsummary` is likely harder.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @r2evans and the aggregation should be done *before* passing the data to `tbl_cross()`. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #Uighur
library(tidyverse)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.2'

tbl <-
  diamonds %>%
  # lump together levels with fewer than 1000 observations
  mutate(clarity = fct_lump_min(clarity, min = 1000)) %>%
  tbl_cross(clarity, color)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>